# Unpredictable connection to Xbox Live with Belkin F5D8235-4 v2000

Tags: wireless-networking, connection, xbox360

I have a Belkin F5D8235-4 v2000 router, and I am not able to connect to Xbox Live very good. I have a good connection, as when downloading files I can occasionally hit up to 2 MB/s, and I can talk on Skype/browse the web fine. My connection is VERY unpredictable on Xbox Live. Like it jumps from 1 bar, to 4 bars in 10 seconds. My Xbox is on a wireless connection(and so is the laptop that can do this stuff).

My router has little to no interference as you can see (the green one is mine):

[image]

Also, I was just reading on something about DD-WRT. Could this help my problem, as I am on the latest firmware for my router, and it still lacks features such as port triggering.

I have forwarded the following ports to my Xbox:

[image]

Would installing DD-WRT be a solution? I don't know anything about it, but just viewing the photos seems like it has alot of nice features.

Comment: The [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq) explicitly classifies questions about videogames or consoles as off topic.

Comment: @Dennis it has to do with home networking, I think it's fine here

Comment: @SimonSheehan: I based my vote on the fact that the OP's problems only seem to happen with the Xbox.

Comment: @Dennis but it appears to be a problem originating at his router.

Comment: @SimonSheehan: Gladly, a single close vote makes no difference.

Comment: It is my first post here, and yes it all goes back to my router. I am asking for suggestions on DD-WRT and stuff. Are you really going to give me a hard time?

Comment: @hetelek We generally move questions about consoles to a gaming website, but since its your router it will stay here

Comment: I know this might sound strange, but do you have another XBox 360 to try?

Comment: Yes I do, which is wired. My wired connection seems better than the wireless, but it still is a little bit unpredictable, but nothing like the wireless.

Comment: If this problem is the router's fault I do not think DD-WRT would be a solution.

Comment: Also, have you tried using another router to ensure it is the culprit?

Comment: No I actually have not, I will do that. I just assumed because Skype and other applications work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions you can try to pinpoint your problem.

1. Can you use a tp-cable and see if your gaming/connectivity is improves.
2. Can you move your xbox closer to the router and use wifi and see if this works without the trouble you are having now.

If the use of cable works flawless we have established that the router, routerconfiguration and your internetconnection is not a total piece of crap. That is a good start ;) Downloading files is not always a good measure if you have good stable connection for example torrents are very resilient even with the most unreliable connection. If it is still unreliable when using cable... look for firmware update from belkin first.

The second test to use the xbox close to the router is to make sure that it is not just a weak signal that is causing your problem. If there is a problem with the firmware making some weird stuff it should be noticable even when closeby. There also could be other things that are faulty like the xbox wifi adapter. If the signal is weak and everything works fine when the router and xbox is close maybe you can move them closer? Some brands and firmwares have the possibility to set output effect of wifi.

ok now back to your question... is DD-wrt gonna solve everything magically? I don't have a clue. To be able to answer that question I would have to know what is wrong and I can't tell from your description. I can only give you a few suggestions on how to start looking for the cause of the error. I hope it is helpful to you.

I know several that use DD-WRT with success but none started using it becasue they had bad working wifi. They just wanted the improved configuration possibilities that comes with it. Is it even possible to install DD-WRT on your router? I don't see it in the database
http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database